# Where in Vedas it is written that Vedas are incomplete without Ithihas and Puranas?

Tags: mahabharata, vedas, puranas, ramayana

All scholars agree that Vedas should be understood completely when you interpret Vedas with Puranas and Ithihas. Where in Vedas it is stated like that?

Comment: Attharva Veda  11:7:24,chandogya upanishad 7:1:12 and brihardankya upanishad says puranas and epics form the fifth Veda.

Comment: @Karmanya Nanda you should write that as an answer

Comment: actually I have never given an answer so I was not enough confident to write an  answer but I will try to give answer with more details:)

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda You should  give an answer. You will gain confidence by doing that.

Comment: Guys I just answered if there are any mistakes in my answer then tell me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both Itihasa and Puranas are considered eternal texts as they also have appeared from The Supreme person's breath:

> "O Maitreya,The Rg,yajur,sama and atharva vedas as well as the
>   itihasas and the puranas all manifest from the breathing Of the Lord"
>   (Brihad-aranyaka Upanishad 2.4.10)
>
> "In this way,all the vedas were manifested along with kalpas,Rahasyas
>   ,Brahmanas,Upanishads,Itihasas,Anvakhyatas and the puranas." (Gopatha
>   Brahmana,purva 2.10)
>
> "Indeed, Rg,Yajur, sama and Atharva are the names Of four vedas.The
>   itihasas and puranas are the fifth veda." (Chandogya Upanishad 7.1.4)
>
> Verses, and songs,and magic hymns,purana,sacrificial text.all the
>   celestial Gods whose home is heaven sprang from the residue.(Atharva
>   Veda book 11,hymn 7 verse 24).

Comment: For yellow-quote ( called block quote) use the 4th link found at the top of the text box.

Comment: @KarmanyaNanda For more editing tools, click on "?" symbol. Visit [help centre](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: FYI, [Śaṅkarācārya's commentary on Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad 2.4.10](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117950.html) says the word itihāsaḥ in the context means the Brāhmaṇas not Rāmāyaṇa or Mahābhārata. Also, for purāṇam, he says "Mythology, such as, ‘This universe was in the beginning unmanifest,’ etc. (Tai. II. 7)."

Comment: @Sv ok so according to adi shankara commentary it means brahmanas and stories of universe,what he says about chandogya hymn do you have chandogya upanishad with adi shankara commentary available?

Comment: Yes, I did also look up Śaṅkarācārya's commentary on Chāndogya. You can see it [here](https://archive.org/stream/Shankara.Bhashya-Chandogya.Upanishad-Ganganath.Jha.1942.English#page/n383/mode/2up) on archive.org. There he says it means Mahābhārata because Mahābhārata is generally referred to as the fifth Veda. But I find OP's question a little deceptive because he poses the question as if he's looking for references in Veda saṁhitās but both your and his answer rely on references from Upaniṣads which were clearly later additions to the Vedas.

Answer (score 2):

**Chandogya Upanishad 7.1.4**

> Nama va rig-vedo yajur-vedah
>   Sama-veda atharvanas
>   Caturtha
>   itihasa-puranah
>   Pancamo vedanam vedah

**Meaning:**

> Indeed **Rig, Yajur, Sama, and Atharva** are the names of the **four Vedas**.
>   The **Itihasas and Puranas** are the **fifth Veda**.

**Atharva Veda 11.7.24**

> Rcah samani chandamsi 
>   Puranam yajusa saha
>   Ucchistaj-jajnire sarve divi 
>   Deva divi-sritahpuranam yajusa saha

**Meaning:**

> The **Rig, Sama, Yajur and Atharva became manifest from the Lord, along
>   with the Puranas** and all the Devas residing in the heavens.

Comment: Can you tell me how can we mark answer in yellow colour?

Comment: @Karmanya Nanda you should first visit the tour page.