# Where Epics and Puranas are mentioned as 5th Veda?

Tags: vedas, mahabharata, puranas, ramayana

There are 4 vedas - Rigveda, Yajurveda, Samaveda and Atharvaveda.

But in several places few scriptures are mentioned as 5th Veda, such as:

**Mahabharata**

[image]

> The boon-giving great one then taught Sumanta, Jaimini, Paila, his son Suka, and Vaisampayana, **the Vedas having the Mahabharata for their fifth**. -[Adi Parva: Adivansavatarana Parva of Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01064.htm)

**Purāṇas**

> ṛg-yajuḥ-sāmātharvākhyā
>
> vedāś catvāra uddhṛtāḥ
>
> itihāsa-purāṇaṁ ca
>
> **pañcamo veda** ucyate
>
> The four divisions of the original sources of knowledge [the Vedas] were made separately. But the historical facts and authentic stories mentioned in the **Purāṇas are called the fifth Veda**. -[SB 1.4.20](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/4/20)

Similarly, I heard that Epics (Ramayana and Mahabharata) are called as 5th Veda or sometimes Epics and Puranas collectively called as 5th Veda.

So, is there any scripture where Ramayana is mentioned as 5th Veda or Epics collectively are mentioned as 5th Veda?

Comment: Related [Where in Vedas it is written that Vedas are incomplete without Ithihas and Puranas?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21460/where-in-vedas-it-is-written-that-vedas-are-incomplete-without-ithihas-and-puran)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Similarly, I heard that Epics (Ramayana and Mahabharata) are called as 5th Veda or sometimes Epics and Puranas collectively called as 5th Veda. So, is there any scripture where Ramayana is mentioned as 5th Veda or Epics collectively are mentioned as 5th Veda?

Yes, there is.  First of all, the Bhagavatam is one of them, in fact the very Bhagavatam [verse](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/4/20) you quoted:

> ṛg-yajuḥ-sāmātharvākhy vedāś catvāra uddhṛtāḥ 
>   itihāsa-purāṇaṁ ca pañcamo veda ucyate

It's just a translation issue; the verse is actually saying that Itihasas (epics) and Puranas together constitute the fifth Veda.

In any case, [another chapter](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/12/chapter-view) of the Sriman Bhagavatam provides more detail on this:

> Beginning from the front face of Brahmā, gradually the four Vedas — Ṛk, Yajur, Sāma and Atharva — became manifest. Thereafter, Vedic hymns which had not been pronounced before, priestly rituals, the subject matters of the recitation, and transcendental activities were all established, one after another. He also created the medical science, military art, musical art and architectural science, all from the Vedas. They all emanated one after another, beginning from the front face. Then he created the fifth Veda — the Purāṇas and the histories — from all his mouths, since he could see all the past, present and future.

[This chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe01/sbe01135.htm) of the Chandogya Upanishad also says that Itihasas and Puranas are the fifth Veda:

> I know the Rig-veda, Sir, the Yagur-veda, the Sâma-veda, as the fourth the Âtharvana, **as the fifth the Itihâsa-purâna**; the Veda of the Vedas; the Pitrya; the Râsi; the Daiva; the Nidhi; the Vâkovâky; the Ekâyana; the Deva-vidyâ; the Brahma-vidyâ; the Bhûta-vidyâ; the Kshatra-vidyâ; the Nakshatra-vidyâ (astronomy); the Sarpa and Devagana-vidyâ.

Comment: **He also created the medical science, military art, musical art and architectural science, all from the Vedas.** ---- How? Vedas are just hymns. Right?

Comment: @Tamas. That's just a translation issue.  The verse says "āyur-vedaṁ dhanur-vedaṁ gāndharvaṁ vedam ātmanaḥ |
sthāpatyaṁ cāsṛjad vedaṁ kramāt pūrvādibhir mukhaiḥ ||" It doesn't say they emerged from the Vedas, it says they emerged from Brahms's mouth starting from his front mouth.  It's just that the translator took "vedam" as an independent word rather than part of Gandharva Veda.  In any case, the Vedas aren't just hymns.  The Samhitas consist of hymns, but the Vedas consist of Samhitas, Brahmanas, Aranyakas, and Upanishads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer however the word Ramyana or Epic is missing. If the special mention of Ramayana (same as Mahabharata) can be found it would be great. As in the verse I quoted itihāsa is translated as "historical facts & authentic stories (found in Puranas)" and not Epics, so few people may translate these verse also in that way. However it is well known that Epics are also called itihāsa so if no other answer received, I shall be accepting this as an answer...

Comment: @YDS The word epic is not missing, epic is just an English translation for Itihasa, which is the actual Sanskrit term for the Ramayana and Mahabharata.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think actual Sanskrit word for Epic is **काव्य  (Kavya)**

Comment: @YDS Kavya is a more general category of poetry, but Itihasa is the specific term for the Ramayana and Mahabharata.  It is the Itihasas and Puranas that constitute the 5th Veda, not Kayvas in general.

Answer (score 3):

Chhandogya Upanishad 7.1.4, 7.2.1, 7.7.1; Bhagavata Purana 1.4.20, 3.12.37; Skanda Purana 5.3.1 state that:

“Itihasa are the epic histories like Ramayana and Mahabharata. Itihasa and Purana extend the message of the 4 Veda. Therefore, Itihasa and Purana are collectively called the fifth Veda.”

Source: The book ‘Essence of the Fifth Veda’ by Gaurang Damani

Comment: Welcome to the Hinduism SE! "Source: The book ‘Essence of the Fifth Veda’ by Gaurang Damani" -- can u pls make it more specific like chapter/page number? also, are u author of this book or some other Gaurang Damani? :)

Comment: This is the opening page of the book 'Essence of the Fifth Veda' published by Motilal Banarsidass Publishing House (mlbd.in). Yes, I am the author of this book. Thank you.

Comment: wow...!! thanks for choosing Hinduism SE...

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and the kind words.

Answer (score 2):

In many sruti scriptures it is mentioned that puranas and Itihasa are fifth Veda.

> "Nârada said: 'I know the Rig-veda, Sir, the Yagur-veda, the
>   Sâma-veda, as the fourth the Âtharvana, as the fifth the
>   Itihâsa-purâna (the Bhârata); the Veda of the Vedas (grammar); the
>   Pitrya (the rules for the sacrifices for the ancestors); the Râsi (the
>   science of numbers); the Daiva (the science of portents); the Nidhi
>   (the science of time); the Vâkovâkya (logic); the Ekâyana (ethics);
>   the Deva-vidyâ (etymology); the Brahma-vidyâ (pronunciation, sikshâ,
>   ceremonial, kalpa, prosody, khandas); the Bhûta-vidyâ (the science of
>   demons); the Kshatra-vidyâ - **Chāndogya Upaniṣad 7.1.2.**
>
> "A name is the Rig-veda, Yagur-veda, Sâma-veda, and as the fourth the
>   Âtharvana, as the fifth the Itihâsa-purâna, the Veda of the Vedas, the
>   Pitrya, the Râsi, the Daiva, the Nidhi, the Vâkovâkya, the Ekâyana,
>   the Deva-vidyâ, the Brahma-vidyâ, the Bhûta-vidyâ, the Kshatra-vidyâ,
>   the Nakshatra-vidyâ, the Sarpa and Devagana-vidyâ. All these are a
>   name only. Meditate on the name. - **"Chāndogya Upaniṣad 7.1.4.**
>
> "As clouds of smoke proceed by themselves out of a lighted fire
>   kindled with damp fuel, thus, verily, O Maitreyî, has been breathed
>   forth from this great Being what we have as Rig-veda, Yagur-veda,
>   Sama-veda, Atharvâṅgirasas, Itihâsa (legends), Purâna (cosmogonies),
>   Vidyâ (knowledge), the Upanishads, Slokas (verses), Sûtras (prose
>   rules), Anuvyâkhyânas (glosses), Vyâkhyânas (commentaries). From him
>   alone all these were breathed forth. - **"Bṛhad-āraṇyaka Upaniṣad
>   2.4.10.**
>
> "In this way all the Vedas are manifested along with the
>   kalpas,rahasyas, Brahmanas, Upanishads, Itihas, anvakhyatas and the
>   puranas." - **Gopatha Brahman purva 2:10.**